# css - Why is there a big white space between text lines?

Tags: html, css, text, whitespace

I'm working on a website and currently working on the middle box.
The news will be in the middle box but its a big white space between the text lines.

It looks like this:
[image]

How could I make the lines to be closer to each other.

For example:

**Hello World!

This is a test**

instead of

**Hello World!


This is a test**

I'm using `< p >` tags.

I can't find anything that would fix it.
There's no padding that will effect it and no margin or something either.
I've also tried applying the line-height to the `<p>` tags

Comment: Are you sure you tried setting `margin` and `padding` to 0?

Comment: try adding `* {margin:0;padding:0;}` otherwise please use devtools to inspect the DOM and identify what is causing the space + if you need a better answer share your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
p,h2{
    line-height:0px
    }
```

```html
<h2>Hello world</h2>
<p>ajsdkjahsdhalkshdklashdkjhasjdklajshdkjashdl</p>
<p>ajsdkjahsdhalkshdklashdkjhasjdklajshdkjashdl</p>
```

You can use `line-height` CSS property, It will allow you to change the gap as desired

Comment: Semi-related, for zero unit values in CSS, the unit suffix is not required, so you can simply do `line-height:0`

Comment: Y a downwote? Please give some reasons

Answer (score 2):

to set the space between the paragraphs, simply set the margins:

```
p{
    margin-bottom: 0px; // or any other value
}
```

and to set the spacing of the lines in a paragraph use `line-height`!

Answer (score 1):

It could be `line-height`, or maybe you have set a `margin`/`padding` on the `p`

Answer (score 0):

You can add css for that. use like below. It will decrease the space height between 2 lines according u set.

```
<style>
p {
    line-height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `<p>` tag is meant for a new alinea. When you want to print things line by line I'd advise using `<br />`, which makes your intensions clearer.

Also, you could set the margin to 0, as others have pointed out. Best to do that in a seperate span/div, as not to affect the rest of the page. Example below.

```css
.no-space-p p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>First line</p>
<p>Second line</p>

<p>Third line
    <br/>Fourth line</p>

<span class="no-space-p">
    <p>Fifth line</p>
    <p>Sixth line</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
p {
-webkit-margin-before: 0px;
-webkit-margin-after: 0px;
}
</style>
```

you can also try this